# How to use cgroup in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: cpu, cgroup

I'm trying to learn how `cgroup` works on Ubuntu and seems that `cgroup` doesn't work in Ubuntu 13.04. I am using the answer to this question [How to set cpu limit for given process permanently. Cpulimit and nice don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94619/how-to-set-cpu-limit-for-given-process-permanently-cpulimit-and-nice-dont-workcpulimit-and-nice-dont-work)

These are what I've done:

1. Installed `cgroup`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cgroup-bin
   ```
2. reboot
3. Make a `cgroup` for your user (the owner of the process):

   ```
   sudo cgcreate -a ipeacocks -g cpu:ipeacocks
   ```
4. Ran the command:

   ```
   echo 100 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/ipeacocks/cpu.shares
   ```
5. And the command:

   ```
   cgexec -g cpu:ipeacocks stress --cpu 4
   ```

and output:

```
cgroup change of group failed
```

Why? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to be the owner of the tasks file as well so you have permission to write a pid to it.  To do that, Use -t, e.g.,

```
sudo cgcreate -a $USER:$USER -t $USER:$USER -g cpu:ipeacocks
```

Comment: yes, that was it. A pity I cannot mark at solved. @ipeacocks, would you?

Comment: just to help a bit `sudo cgcreate -a $USER:$USER -t $USER:$USER -g ...`

Comment: I had to run additionally this command to make the error go away: `chmod 711 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct`

Comment: Didn't work on Ubuntu 22.04 which now has cgroups v2 unfortunately: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406329/how-to-run-cgexec-without-sudo-as-current-user-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-cgroups-v2