# Cgroups error: cgroup change of group failed

Tags: cgroup

I'm trying to test cgroup and, after I set it, I stumbled upon that error. That's what I did:

- creation of the group *grp*
- creation of the user *test* within the *grp* group

I ran the command:

```
sudo cgcreate -t test:grp -a sleax -g memory,cpu:grp
echo '10000000'> /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/grp/memory.limit_in_bytes
```

Then i went to try that with the user *test*:

```
test@sleax-PC:~$ cgexec stress -t 20 -c 99 -i 99
cgroup change of group failed
```

And that's the error I get. Why? I set `-t test:grp` so *test* is able to write the PIDs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use cgroup in ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345055/how-to-use-cgroup-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 6):

Specifying users and groups works fine when you create a subsystem.

```
sudo cgcreate -t $USER:$USER -a $USER:$USER  -g cpu:testgroupcpu
```

["cgroup change of group failed" error with cgexec from libcgroup](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169638)

Comment: I had to run additionally this command to make the error go away: `chmod 711 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct`

Comment: Update: More correct version would be probably `chmod 751 /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct` since the initial permission of that folder is `750`.

Comment: Did not work on Ubuntu 22.04 unfortunately: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406329/how-to-run-cgexec-without-sudo-as-current-user-on-ubuntu-22-04-with-cgroups-v2